# Calculation of binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics

I just want to ask how to calculate, if I have: 
$$\binom{17}{8,9}$$
Thanks

Comment: Usually one writes $\binom {17 }8=\binom {17 }9=\dfrac {17!}{8!9!}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks, I know that it was stupid question, but I was unable to find it

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That's a full answer. Why not put it as an answer?

Comment: Did you mean a multinomial coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the numer of partitions of $17$ objects  into two sets of $8$ and $9$ objects is the same as choosing $8$ out of $17$ objects the answer is $$\binom {17}{8}=\frac {17!}{8!9!}$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Usually one writes $17 \choose 8$ for the binomial coefficient, and it can be calculated as $\binom {17} 8 = \dfrac {17!}{8!9!}$

$=\dfrac{17\times16\times15\times14\times13\times12\times11\times10}{8\times7\times6\times5\times4\times3\times2}$ $=\dfrac{17\times2\times5\times2\times13\times2\times11\times2}{ 4\times2}$

$={17\times5\times13\times11\times2}=24310.$

Note that $\binom {17}8=\binom{17}9$.